# Client channel factory for WCF Data Services

Tags: wcf-data-services

I hate using service references for many different reasons, instead I use interfaces and System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory

I would like to be able to use something similar when connecting to WCF Data Services.

I mean when I'm creating the DataService Endpoint it's just DataService why can't I new up a DataServiceContext when creating the client and have access to all the IQueryables in MyDataService.

eg

Common

```
public interface IMyDataService
{
  public IQueryable<Foo> Foos {get;set;}
  public IQueryable<OtherFoo> OtherFoos {get;set;}
}
```

Server

```
public class MyDataService : IMyDataService
{
  public IQueryable<Foo> Foos {get;set;}
  public IQueryable<OtherFoo> OtherFoos {get;set;}
}
public class DataService : DataService<MyDataService>
{
}
```

Client

```
var context = new DataServiceContext<IMyDataService>();
var foo = context.Foos.First(f=>f.Id = 5);
var otherFoos = contact.OtherFoos.Where(of=>of.width > 6);
```

Edit: I have a solution where I create a proxy class of IMyDataService however it's my understanding that this would be pretty hard on a server. Anyone know anything about the performance impact of creating a proxy using the method detailed here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dynamicproxy.aspx

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific? You can definitely just new up a DataServiceContext without the generated classes. It won't be able to do much without a client side class, but you can new it up. To run queries you need at least some client class so that the context can create instances of those types to represent entities on the client. But you can specify the type when issues a request in the Execute method (it's the generic parameter) or in CreateQuery method.

Comment: Ok edited to be more specific